# Привлекли к работе таких специалистов, как психолог(а) и юрист(а)

Tags: грамматика

"Привлекли к работе в центре таких специалистов, как психолог и юрист" или "Привлекли к работе в центре таких специалистов, как психолога и юриста"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Привлекли к работе в центре таких специалистов, как психолог и юрист.

**Пояснение**

**Такие, как / таких, как / таким, как** - все эти конструкции относятся к **несобственно сравнительным** оборотам (их частное значение - **определительно-репрезентирующее**), например: **Такие** поэты, **как Пушкин**, появляются очень редко.

Для этих оборотов характерно то, что при любой падежной форме соотносительного слова ТАКОЙ, предмет сравнения стоит в И.п.

Примеры

К 1917 г. в батареях стал ощущаться недостаток хорошо подготовленных фейерверкеров и **таких** специалистов, **как наводчики и разведчики**.

Полагаю, что **таким** специалистам, как **Красин**, воспроизвести «в упрощенном варианте» почерк «кандидата в покойники» было не слишком трудно.

Answer (score 0):

"Таких как" требует именительного падежа.

***"Привлекли к работе в центре таких специалистов, как психолог и юрист"***.

И не забывайте кавычки ставить в вопросе. Да и прочие знаки препинания.